# iOS - KeyValueStore not working across devices

Tags: ios, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I have an app that will implement key value store in order to save some variables and sync across devices.

I have a view controller with the following:

```
var keyStore: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore?
```

On viewDidLoad I do

```
keyStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore()
```

Then when a user finishes watching a video I run

```
keyStore?.set(num, forKey: "watched") // where num is a number
keyStore?.synchronize()
```

In order to check the value of the "watched" variable, I'm running this on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
keyStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore()
let val = keyStore?.string(forKey: "watched")
print(val)
```

If I test the app several times, the value of val changes accordingly. However, when I test on a different device, val returns nul. If I use the application in this new device, the value for "watched" changes but values never sync between the two devices.

I read that there is a Notification Method to check if the stored value changed in real time, but in this case I'm reading the stored value during app launch. Wouldn't that make it unneeded?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Make sure you are logged into Cloud in your simulator.